# An alchemist without spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

One of my players asked if there is any way to replace the alchemist's spell list with a different class feature. They want an "alchemist without spellcasting."

So, is there any possibility of a alchemist without the entire list of spells? Some kind of archetype, maybe? Just eliminating six levels of spellcasting without trading it out for some other class feature would be drastically underpowered, of course.

Comment: Alchemists don't have spells.  They have "alchemical extracts." None of the extant archetypes replace it because it's really what defines an alchemist; this is kinda like asking for "a wizard without spells." What kind of character do they want specifically out of what's left, is it the poison use or bombs or what, there might be a different way of simulating that?

Answer (score 1):

So you want a class with Bomb, Mutagen and Poison features but with no Potions and Extracts? There is a character that can throw stuff at people to great effect, transform into rampaging beast with beastly attributes and well, use poison too. That character is called **a barbarian**.

Jokes aside, there is a 3rd party [Mutagenic Rager](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/barbarian-archetypes---flaming-crab-games/mutagenic-rager) archetype that exchanges rage feature line for mutagen feature line. An interesting idea for a start, but completely changes how Barbarians work. Usually you want to either ragecycle (exit and enter rage every turn) to maximise once-per-rage powers or maximise the amount of time you can rage at once. Here, you can only rage once daily but for a prolonged amount of time.

Now, [Hurling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo---rage-powers/hurling-ex) is a great line in its own right and you can combine its power with Dexterity-improving mutagen. You can also get a a level in [Assassin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/assassin) prestige class to get poison use class feature and then immediately switch to [Guild Poisoner](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/guild-poisoner) and get all manner of poison-brewing goodness. At Guild Poisoner level 2 you will get [Toxic Trick](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/guild-poisoner#TOC-Toxic-Trick) and by carefully selecting bomb-related tricks (Smoke Bomb, Poison Bomb) you can spend your Trick quota to throw poison bombs at people. Granted, they don't explode, just put enemies in writhing agony.

To sum up, you can totally play a **poison-hurling barbarian on roid-rage**.
[Sounds familiar?](http://www.cinemablend.com/images/news/31856/Prepare_For_The_Dark_Knight_Rises_Revisiting_Batman_Robin_1342118395.jpg)

You can also as Nox rightly said, play [Pathfinder community](http://www.pathfindercommunity.net/classes/multiclass-archetypes) suggestions. One that stands out is a [Demolitionist](http://www.pathfindercommunity.net/classes/multiclass-archetypes/fighter/demolitionist-fighter-alchemist) which combines full attack progression of Fighters and bombs of Alchemists. However, it also lets go of Mutagens and Poisons, in favor of getting blast resistance mutagens and some bonus feats. It sounds quite awesome, running around blowing stuff up and might be what you are looking for.